# gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Tags: log, 19.04

Since updating from a new install of 18.10 to 19.04 I am getting this error in my syslog sent from gdm-session-wor:

> gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

What does it mean? Other than the log entry I am not experiencing any problems.

Comment: Think that this may be related to https://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg752099.html